# How can I create a week-to-date metric in vertica?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table which stores year-to-date metrics once per client per day. The schema simplified looks roughly like so, lets call this table history::

```
bus_date | client_id | ytd_costs
```

I'd like to create a view that adds a week-to-date costs, essentially any cost that occurs after the prior friday would be considered part of the week-to-date. Currently, I have the following but I'm concerned about the switch case logic.

Here is an example of the logic I have right now to show that this works.
I also got to use the timeseries clause which I've never used before...

```
;with history as (
select bus_date,client_id,ts_first_Value(value,'linear') "ytd_costs"
from (select {ts'2016-10-07'} t,1 client_id,5.0 "value" union all select {ts'2016-10-14'},1, 15) k
timeseries bus_Date as '1 day' over (partition by client_id order by t)
)
,history_with_wtd as (select bus_date
    ,client_id
    ,ytd_costs
    ,ytd_costs - decode(
      dayofweek(bus_date)
      ,6,first_value(ytd_costs) over (partition by client_id order by bus_date range '1 week' preceding)
      ,first_value(ytd_costs) over (partition by client_id,date_trunc('week',bus_date+3) order by bus_date)
   ) as "wtd_costs"
    ,ytd_costs - 5 "expected_wtd"
from history)
select *
from history_with_wtd
where date_trunc('week',bus_date) = '2016-10-10'
```

In Sql server, I could just use the lag function, as I can pass a variable to the look-back clause. but in Vertica no such option exists.

Answer (score 0):

How about you partition by week starting on Saturday? First grab the first day of the week, then offset to start on Saturday. `trunc(bus_date + 1,'D') - 1`

Also notice the window frame is from the start of the partition (Saturday, `unbounded preceding`) to the `current row`.

```
select 
   bus_date
  ,client_id
  ,ytd_costs
  ,ytd_costs - first_value(ytd_costs) over (
                        partition by client_id, trunc(bus_date + 1,'D') - 1 
                        order by bus_date 
                        range between unbounded preceding and current row) wtd_costs
from sos.history
order by client_id, bus_date
```

Comment: Doesn't give the right result, as ytd_cost is a cumulative value. Thus if my cost on friday was $5, and I incurred an additional $10 of expenses on monday my value will be $15. On tuesday if I incur no additional fees, it'd be still $15.

Comment: So the first day's value (Saturday) will be Saturday minus Friday?

Comment: So wouldn't that just be what I have above already, except make it use `first_value` and subtract it from `ytd_costs`?  I'll update the query for this version.

Comment: I'm also a little confused about the date boundary. If you have a short example of the data and the output that would help.

Comment: I updated my example to query what the boundry should be. Using a sliding window that includes the friday is problematic because it would then consider the cost on friday to be 0. 
So if on friday, the 7th my ytd cost was $5, on friday the 14th my ytd cost was $15, then my wtd on the 14th should be $10. (see example)